# Tic-Tac-Toe AI with multi dimensional arrays and turtles

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game by using turtles to draw the board on Repl.it. Not super efficient, but I'm trying to developed an AI without having to program every possible board combination.

I'm still very new to python; I'm taking an AP ComSciPri class in school. I've learned a lot of basics in terms of functions and calculations and such, but in the grand scheme of things I'm missing a lot. Aside from creating branches to tie every game, is there a way create a procedure to do this?

### Not sure if this is helpful but:

```
gameArray = [["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]

uArray = [["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"]]

cpuArray = [["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"]]

winningArrays = [
[["X","X","X"],["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"]],
[["0","0","0"],["X","X","X"],["0","0","0"]],
[["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"],["X","X","X"]],
[["X","0","0"],["X","0","0"],["X","0","0"]],
[["0","X","0"],["0","X","0"],["0","X","0"]],
[["0","0","X"],["0","0","X"],["0","0","X"]],
[["X","0","0"],["0","X","0"],["0","0","X"]],
[["0","0","X"],["0","X","0"],["X","0","0"]]]
```

---

Im using turtles to draw a board and place stamps, as well as manipulate the debug boards (gameArray, uArray, cpuArray).

---

if userInput == 1:

```
spaceList.remove(1)

turt1.shape("circle")

turt1.color("black")

turt1.penup()

turt1.goto(-75,-25)

turt1.stamp()

gameArray[2][0] = "U"

uArray[2][0] = "X"
```

---

Ill link what I have in [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/ezojonobat.md). Mostly I wanted some information on something I could research or if anyone had any advice to give me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at MinMax aproach, i did a tictactoe in python and the AI used Min Max algorithm

Comment: This is not really related to your question, but your definition for `winningArrays` SCREAMS "I'm new to programming".  One of the things to think about when writing code is scalability.  If we needed to scale this tic-tac-toe game up to a 7x7 grid, you would have a LOT of work to do on your `winningArrays` definition.  If you can, I suggest finding a different way to determine if a certain board is a winning board. I'm sure your teacher will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing you need to have an AI is a metric for how good or bad a board state is.  As an incredibly simple example, lets say the metric will be whether the board is in a winning state (three Xs in a row).  Then have the AI check all the different boards it can make on its turn (up to 9) and, if one was a winner, we pick that one! Otherwise just pick something randomly. This should certainly do better than random chance and might be a good 'easy mode' computer player for your program.  If you can create a more intricate function for which board state is better, you can create a more intricate computer player.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply!
My current program already uses a random selection feature to pick spaces. However, even if you make mistakes its still hard to lose, so ill definitely try implementing a more specific selection! Do you have any suggestions for how to approach this?

In regards to your other comment: that would be because I AM relatively new to programming. I wrote the program without intending on adding an AI or difficulties to it, so I chose to try a method I wasn't super familiar with and try to learn from it. Regardless, thank you VERY much for your suggestion!

Comment: The "tough part" that I would suggest getting down first would be the metric.  Simply put, a function that takes a board state as input, and spits out a number that is generally higher for boards that are closer to winning, lower for boards that are not close. Once you have this function, making the computer 'choose' a move based on the output of this function should be as easy as finding the maximum number in a list of up to 9.

Comment: Ill put some research into it for sure. Thank you again for your suggestion!